# Halo: Reach Medal Collection

Tags: halo-reach

During progress through the campaign and playing online I have collected A vast amount of medals, is it possible to look at all the medals I have collected so I can see which ones I am missing? I am talking about medals NOT commendations. I can access the commendations in the player menu but I see no option to see my medal collection.

A list of all the medals available is in the link below, I want to compare my collection to the list below so I know which ones I am missing.

http://www.xforgery.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10815

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might check your stats on [www.bungie.net](http://www.bungie.net), you should be able to see all the stats it collects for campaign and matchmaking just by logging in with your Windows Live ID.

[Update] I just checked mine, after you login there's a "Medals" link right under "Career Stats" on the left hand navigation. I believe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Cheers Dude, helped alot